# QML control and business layers

Tags: c++, qt, qtquick2, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols

I am using QML for the first time and am having a hard time to get my code organised between the control and the business layers.

In a very down to earth way, all my events are supposed to be sent to a C++ control layer (a C++ class called **MyController** which inherits from **QObject**). Now **MyController** is supposed to know about the business layer (say its a C++ class called **MyBusiness**) and call its relevant methods.

My **MyBusiness** is actually a complex aggregation of lower level classes which I put together in **main.cpp**.

Previously I was using QtWidget and I was able to create **MyBusiness** via this complex aggregation mentioned above, create **MyController** and provide **MyBusiness** to **MyController** to it to do its job.

Now because of QML's way of working, **MyController** is actually exposed to QML (via QML registration) and **MyController** Q_INVOKABLE functions are called from QML and should in turn call **MyBusiness** functions.

But **MyController** is now actually created in QML so I am no longer able to let **MyController** know about **MyBusiness**.

What is the best practise in my case?

Comment: Consider also publishing a C++ singleton as a QML singleton and then attaching to it explicitly in QML, like that: `MyController { business: MyBusiness; }`.

Comment: Good point, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I do like that:

```
import QtQuick 2.5

Item {
    MyController {
        business: businessObj
    }

    MyBusiness {
        id: businessObj
    }
}
```

In `MyController.h`:

```
class MyController
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(MyBusiness* business MEMBER m_business);
    ...
    MyBusiness *m_business;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the solutions I have thought about:

1. I could create **MyBusiness** within **MyController** but that would be a bit dirty (as the business responsibility should not be in the controller's hands)
2. I could also create a 3rd **MyApplication** class which only purpose would be to join **MyController** and **MyBusiness** but then each time I create a new Q_INVOKABLE function I would have to create the function in **MyApplication** (to be invoked) and pass it through to **MyController** (for it to call **MyBusiness**. It's not that I am lazy but this redundancy would add a maintenance burden
3. I could make a singleton of **MyBusiness** and call it from **MyController**
4. I could use @Velkan's approach (see above)

I have decided to go for solution 3 (as it better suits my use case) but solution 4 (from @Vulkan) is also valuable in some use cases. Solutions 1 and 2 are less valuable.